# LocalDB Error with LightSwitch

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch

**Issue**: When creating a new project using Microsoft Lightswitch and attempt to build the project after adding 1 table and 1 form, I get the following error:

An error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server Instance '(LocalDB\MSSQLLocalDB'. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection the SQL Server....(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50...)

**Steps I have done to attempt to resolve**: I have navigated to the bin\Data folder but found no .mdf created there. It's as if VS isn't creating the file.
I have attempted to access my own personal local server (william-pc\sqlexpress). Still, it states the same message.

**Platform Information**: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise - Windows 10 - SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a missing dependency.  You may need to install SQL Server LocalDB.

Download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Further information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Shouldn't that come with sql server 2014?

Comment: I verified that I have the following:

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB installed via the control panel. What else could it be?

Comment: I would try running Visual Studio as an Administrator, repairing the LocalDB installer, installing the 2012 LocalDB program or locating the article that explains how to decouple LocalDB from your LightSwitch application and use a SQL Server Instance instead.